# Custom Bentley InRoads Report - xsl file with simple JavaScript math function producing +/- 0.05 error and i don't know why?

Tags: javascript, xslt

I’m trying to understand why my custom InRoads XSL report is not generating the result for the Cross Slope value using JavaScript when compared to what I come up with by hand calculation.  Can someone take a look at this please and see what I’m missing… please?

I am trying to create a report that publishes the elevation of the left edge-of-travelway, centerline, and the right edge-of-travelway, also I want it to publish the cross slope of the left travelway and the right travelway and these values would be provided per cross section interval.

I have been able to customize the Evaluation report “Cross Section Points” to return the ‘cross-slope’ percentage by adding a JavaScript function, but this math function that I’ve created always produces an result that is consistently off by 0.06%, is there a rounding issue with JavaScript “toFixed” method?  I have no idea why this function I created is producing a result that is consistently off by this amount.  Is there anyone out there with time to check this out?

[Cross Section of a road with 12' Travelways](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6bbA.png)

This is my custom JavaScript function, (which is the last 13 lines of my custom stylesheet)

```
</xsl:template>
     <msxsl:script implements-prefix="inr" language="JScript">
        <![CDATA[
            // This function derives the slope between the CL point
            // and the edge of travelway point both of which are at
            // existing ground elevation.
            function DeterimeSlope(clelev, etwelev, offset)
            {
              var elevdiff = clelev - etwelev;
              var slope = (Math.abs(elevdiff / offset) * 100).toFixed(2);
              return slope + "%";
            }
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The raw.xml file that has the cross section information in it is “RPT1A0D.xml”, and my custom stylesheet is “MDOT_CrossSectionPoints_WTR_working.xsl”.
This is what my custom report output looks like:

My custom InRoads Report / XSL Style Sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:inr="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace">
    <xsl:include href="../format.xsl"/>
    <xsl:param name="xslRootDirectory" select="inr:xslRootDirectory"/>
    <!-- Unique cross section surfaces -->
    <xsl:variable name="uniqueSurfaceName" select="//CrossSectionSurfaces/CrossSectionSurface[not (@name = preceding::CrossSectionSurface/@name)]/@name"/>
    <!-- Variable to hold number of points reported per line.  Change this value to suit requirements. -->
    <!-- You must also change the table data cells in the showPointData template below to match if you -->
    <!-- change this variable to be other than 5. -->
    <xsl:variable name="pointsPerLine" select="5"/>
    <!-- Cross Section Points Report -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="gridOut" select="inr:SetGridOut(number(InRoads/@outputGridScaleFactor))"/>
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$xslRootDirectory}/_Themes/engineer/theme.css"/>
                <!-- Title displayed in browser Title Bar -->
                <title lang="en">Cross Section Evaluation Report</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$xslShowHelp = 'true'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="StyleSheetHelp"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:for-each select="InRoads">
                            <center>
                                <!-- Report Title -->
                                <h2 lang="en">Cross Section Evaluation Report</h2>
                                <p lang="en">
                                    Report Created:&#xa0; <xsl:value-of select="inr:date()"/><br />
                                    Time:&#xa0; <xsl:value-of select="inr:time()"/>
                                </p>
                            </center>
                            <!-- Cross Section Set Data -->
                            <xsl:for-each select="CrossSectionSet">
                                <table class="margin" cellpadding="2" width="90%">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th align="right" lang="en">Set Name:&#xa0; </th>
                                            <td align="left" colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="@setName"/></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th align="right" lang="en">Alignment Name:&#xa0; </th>
                                            <td align="left" colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="@alignmentName"/></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th align="right" lang="en" style="font-size: 80%">Input Grid Factor:&#xa0; </th>
                                            <td align="left" style="font-size: 80%"><xsl:value-of select="../@inputGridScaleFactor" /></td>
                                            <td align="right" lang="en" style="font-size: 80%">
                                                <strong>Note:&#xa0; </strong>All units in this report are in
                                                <xsl:if test="//@linearUnits = 'Imperial'">feet</xsl:if>
                                                <xsl:if test="//@linearUnits = 'Metric'">meters</xsl:if>
                                                unless specified otherwise.
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <hr/>
                                <!-- Cross Section Point Data -->
                                <table width="100%">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="$uniqueSurfaceName">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th align="left" lang="en">Surface:&#xa0; </th>
                                            <td align="left" colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="underline" lang="en">Station</th>
                                            <xsl:call-template name="colHead">
                                                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$pointsPerLine"/>
                                            </xsl:call-template>
                                        </tr>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="//CrossSectionSurface[@name = current()]">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">
                                                    <br/><xsl:value-of select="inr:stationFormat(number(../../Station/@externalStation), $xslStationFormat,$xslStationPrecision, string(../../Station/@externalStationName))"/>
                                                </td>
                                                <xsl:for-each select="CrossSectionPoints">
                                                    <xsl:call-template name="showPointData">
                                                        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="CrossSectionPoint"/>
                                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                            </tr>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                        <tr><td colspan="3">&#xa0;</td></tr>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </table>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="colHead">
        <xsl:param name="count"/>
        <xsl:if test="$count != 0">
            <th class="underline" lang="en">Elevation</th>
            <th class="underline" lang="en">Distance</th>
            <th class="underline" lang="en">Cross_Slope</th>
            <xsl:call-template name="colHead">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="showPointData">
        <xsl:param name="list"/>
        <xsl:param name="rest" select="$list[position() &gt; $pointsPerLine]"/>
        <xsl:if test="$list[1]">
            <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                <xsl:value-of select="inr:elevationFormat(number($list[1]/@elevation), $xslElevationPrecision)"/>
            </td>
            <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                <xsl:value-of select="inr:distanceFormat(number($list[1]/@offset), $xslDistancePrecision)"/>
            </td>
            <td align="right" valign="bottom">
            <xsl:value-of select="inr:DeterimeSlope(number($list[2]/@elevation), number($list[1]/@elevation), number($list[1]/@offset))"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$list[2]">
            <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                <xsl:value-of select="inr:elevationFormat(number($list[2]/@elevation), $xslElevationPrecision)"/>
            </td>
            <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                <xsl:value-of select="inr:distanceFormat(number($list[2]/@offset), $xslDistancePrecision)"/>
            </td>
           <td align="right" valign="bottom">
               CL no Slope
            </td>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$list[3]">
            <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                <xsl:value-of select="inr:elevationFormat(number($list[3]/@elevation), $xslElevationPrecision)"/>
            </td>
            <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                <xsl:value-of select="inr:distanceFormat(number($list[3]/@offset), $xslDistancePrecision)"/>
            </td>
             <td align="right" valign="bottom">
               <xsl:value-of select="inr:DeterimeSlope(number($list[2]/@elevation), number($list[3]/@elevation), number($list[3]/@offset))"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$list[4]">
            <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                <xsl:value-of select="inr:elevationFormat(number($list[4]/@elevation), $xslElevationPrecision)"/>
            </td>
            <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                <xsl:value-of select="inr:distanceFormat(number($list[4]/@offset), $xslDistancePrecision)"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$list[5]">
            <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                <xsl:value-of select="inr:elevationFormat(number($list[5]/@elevation), $xslElevationPrecision)"/>
            </td>
            <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                <xsl:value-of select="inr:distanceFormat(number($list[5]/@offset), $xslDistancePrecision)"/>
            </td>
        </xsl:if>
        <!-- Add or remove here if the number of points per line is different from 5. -->
        <xsl:if test="$rest">
            <tr>
                <td>&#xa0;</td>
                <xsl:call-template name="showPointData">
                    <xsl:with-param name="list" select="$rest"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </tr>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="StyleSheetHelp">
        <div class="section1">
            <h4 lang="en">Notes</h4>
            <p class="normal1" lang="en">
                You must have created cross sections along your alignment and the cross section set must 
                have the surfaces and features upon which you wish to report displayed.
            </p>
            <p class="normal1" lang="en">
                You can create the XML data file from the <em>Evaluation &gt; Cross Section &gt; Cross 
                Section Report</em> command or from the <em>End-Area Volumes</em> leaf of the <em>
                Evaluation &gt; Cross Section &gt; Cross Sections</em> command by toggling on the <em>
                Create XML Report</em> option on the <em>General</em> leaf.
            </p>
            <p class="normal1" lang="en">
                This report displays five cross section points and their associated data per line before 
                wrapping to the next line.&#xa0; You can change the number of points per line by changing 
                the value in the <code>pointsPerLine</code> variable near the top of the style sheet and by 
                adding or removing columns in the <code>showPointData</code> template.
            </p>
            <p class="small" lang="en">
                <em>&#xa9; 2006 Bentley Systems, Inc</em>
            </p>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
        <msxsl:script implements-prefix="inr" language="JScript">
        <![CDATA[
            // This function derives the slope between the CL point
            // and the edge of travelway point both of which are at
            // existing ground elevation.
            function DeterimeSlope(clelev, etwelev, offset)
            {
            var elevdiff = clelev - etwelev;
            var slope = (Math.abs(elevdiff / offset) * 100).toFixed(2);
            return slope + "%";
            }
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For example if you look at the last column of the report, this is the slope derived from the difference of the two previous elevations over a distance of 12 feet.  The first value in this column is 5.44% but if you do the math by hand [(616.00 - 615.34) Divided by 12] = 0.055 or 5.5% but my JavaScript in my StyleSheet comes up with 5.44%, I DON'T GET IT?  What Have I Done Wrong?

It isn't just that one instance it appears to be all the instances where my JavaScript function is used except the very first instance (which is the first row, fourth column) which is 8.91%, but after that first instance the rest are all about +/- 0.05% off.

Station Elevation   Distance    Cross_Slope Elevation   Distance    Cross_Slope Elevation   Distance    Cross_Slope

0+00.00 614.93  -12.00  8.91%   616.00  0.00    CL no Slope     615.34  12.00   5.44% incorrect should be 5.50%

0+10.00 614.80  -12.00  9.53%   615.95  0.00    CL no Slope     615.30  12.00   5.36% incorrect should be 5.42%

0+20.00 614.72  -12.00  10.05%  615.92  0.00    CL no Slope     615.24  12.00   5.72% incorrect should be 5.67%

0+30.00 614.72  -12.00  9.62%   615.88  0.00    CL no Slope     615.21  12.00   5.54% incorrect should be 5.58%

0+40.00 614.77  -12.00  9.04%   615.85  0.00    CL no Slope     615.19  12.00   5.51% incorrect should be 5.50%

0+50.00 614.83  -12.00  7.92%   615.78  0.00    CL no Slope     615.13  12.00   5.40% incorrect should be 5.42%

The source XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<InRoads productName="Bentley InRoads Suite V8i (SELECTseries 2)" productVersion="08.11.07.630" outputGridScaleFactor="1.000000" inputGridScaleFactor="1.000000" linearUnits="Imperial" angularUnits="Degrees" commandName="Cross Section Report">
    <CrossSectionSet setID="3" setName="Ex-XSlope-Test" alignmentOID="{D97B6FD8-920B-40F1-8F03-6019AEFF8978}" alignmentName="Ex-XSlope-Test">
        <CrossSectionStations>
            <CrossSectionStation leftOffset="-15.000000" rightOffset="15.000000" tangentialDirection="0.848102" radialDirection="2.418899" northing="735891.301345" easting="1692710.841221" elevation="615.997065" longitudinalGrade="-0.003648">
                <Station internalStation="0.000050" externalStationName="" externalStation="0.000050"/>
                <CrossSectionSurfaces>
                    <CrossSectionSurface name="LIDAR existing conditions x-sections only" type="0">
                        <CrossSectionPoints>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735900.301651" easting="1692702.904343" offset="-11.999981" elevation="614.927381" flag="Begin"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="ExistingCenterline" northing="735891.301331" easting="1692710.841234" offset="0.000019" elevation="615.997065"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735882.301012" easting="1692718.778125" offset="12.000019" elevation="615.343766" flag="End"/>
                        </CrossSectionPoints>
                    </CrossSectionSurface>
                </CrossSectionSurfaces>
            </CrossSectionStation>
            <CrossSectionStation leftOffset="-15.000000" rightOffset="15.000000" tangentialDirection="0.848102" radialDirection="2.418899" northing="735897.915389" easting="1692718.341450" elevation="615.947748" longitudinalGrade="-0.006215">
                <Station internalStation="10.000000" externalStationName="" externalStation="10.000000"/>
                <CrossSectionSurfaces>
                    <CrossSectionSurface name="LIDAR existing conditions x-sections only" type="0">
                        <CrossSectionPoints>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735906.915708" easting="1692710.404559" offset="-12.000000" elevation="614.804465" flag="Begin"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="ExistingCenterline" northing="735897.915389" easting="1692718.341450" offset="-0.000000" elevation="615.947748"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735888.915069" easting="1692726.278342" offset="12.000000" elevation="615.303967" flag="End"/>
                        </CrossSectionPoints>
                    </CrossSectionSurface>
                </CrossSectionSurfaces>
            </CrossSectionStation>
            <CrossSectionStation leftOffset="-15.000000" rightOffset="15.000000" tangentialDirection="0.848102" radialDirection="2.418899" northing="735904.529465" easting="1692725.841717" elevation="615.924367" longitudinalGrade="-0.003074">
                <Station internalStation="20.000000" externalStationName="" externalStation="20.000000"/>
                <CrossSectionSurfaces>
                    <CrossSectionSurface name="LIDAR existing conditions x-sections only" type="0">
                        <CrossSectionPoints>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735913.529784" easting="1692717.904825" offset="-12.000000" elevation="614.718334" flag="Begin"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="ExistingCenterline" northing="735904.529465" easting="1692725.841717" offset="-0.000000" elevation="615.924367"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735895.529145" easting="1692733.778608" offset="12.000000" elevation="615.238414" flag="End"/>
                        </CrossSectionPoints>
                    </CrossSectionSurface>
                </CrossSectionSurfaces>
            </CrossSectionStation>
            <CrossSectionStation leftOffset="-15.000000" rightOffset="15.000000" tangentialDirection="0.848102" radialDirection="2.418899" northing="735911.143541" easting="1692733.341983" elevation="615.876978" longitudinalGrade="-0.004556">
                <Station internalStation="30.000000" externalStationName="" externalStation="30.000000"/>
                <CrossSectionSurfaces>
                    <CrossSectionSurface name="LIDAR existing conditions x-sections only" type="0">
                        <CrossSectionPoints>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735920.143861" easting="1692725.405092" offset="-12.000000" elevation="614.723170" flag="Begin"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="ExistingCenterline" northing="735911.143541" easting="1692733.341983" offset="-0.000000" elevation="615.876978"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735902.143221" easting="1692741.278875" offset="12.000000" elevation="615.211808" flag="End"/>
                        </CrossSectionPoints>
                    </CrossSectionSurface>
                </CrossSectionSurfaces>
            </CrossSectionStation>
            <CrossSectionStation leftOffset="-15.000000" rightOffset="15.000000" tangentialDirection="0.848102" radialDirection="2.418899" northing="735917.757617" easting="1692740.842250" elevation="615.852620" longitudinalGrade="-0.002954">
                <Station internalStation="40.000000" externalStationName="" externalStation="40.000000"/>
                <CrossSectionSurfaces>
                    <CrossSectionSurface name="LIDAR existing conditions x-sections only" type="0">
                        <CrossSectionPoints>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735926.757937" easting="1692732.905358" offset="-12.000000" elevation="614.767253" flag="Begin"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="ExistingCenterline" northing="735917.757617" easting="1692740.842250" offset="0.000000" elevation="615.852620"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735908.757297" easting="1692748.779141" offset="12.000000" elevation="615.191458" flag="End"/>
                        </CrossSectionPoints>
                    </CrossSectionSurface>
                </CrossSectionSurfaces>
            </CrossSectionStation>
            <CrossSectionStation leftOffset="-15.000000" rightOffset="15.000000" tangentialDirection="0.848102" radialDirection="2.418899" northing="735924.371693" easting="1692748.342516" elevation="615.782411" longitudinalGrade="-0.007228">
                <Station internalStation="50.000000" externalStationName="" externalStation="50.000000"/>
                <CrossSectionSurfaces>
                    <CrossSectionSurface name="LIDAR existing conditions x-sections only" type="0">
                        <CrossSectionPoints>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735933.372013" easting="1692740.405625" offset="-12.000000" elevation="614.832509" flag="Begin"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="ExistingCenterline" northing="735924.371693" easting="1692748.342516" offset="0.000000" elevation="615.782411"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735915.371373" easting="1692756.279408" offset="12.000000" elevation="615.134286" flag="End"/>
                        </CrossSectionPoints>
                    </CrossSectionSurface>
                </CrossSectionSurfaces>
            </CrossSectionStation>
            <CrossSectionStation leftOffset="-15.000000" rightOffset="15.000000" tangentialDirection="0.848102" radialDirection="2.418899" northing="735930.985769" easting="1692755.842783" elevation="615.764136" longitudinalGrade="-0.002428">
                <Station internalStation="60.000000" externalStationName="" externalStation="60.000000"/>
                <CrossSectionSurfaces>
                    <CrossSectionSurface name="LIDAR existing conditions x-sections only" type="0">
                        <CrossSectionPoints>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735939.986089" easting="1692747.905891" offset="-12.000000" elevation="614.887480" flag="Begin"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="ExistingCenterline" northing="735930.985769" easting="1692755.842783" offset="0.000000" elevation="615.764136"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735921.985449" easting="1692763.779674" offset="12.000000" elevation="615.090532" flag="End"/>
                        </CrossSectionPoints>
                    </CrossSectionSurface>
                </CrossSectionSurfaces>
            </CrossSectionStation>
            <CrossSectionStation leftOffset="-15.000000" rightOffset="15.000000" tangentialDirection="0.848102" radialDirection="2.418899" northing="735937.599845" easting="1692763.343049" elevation="615.721052" longitudinalGrade="-0.005054">
                <Station internalStation="70.000000" externalStationName="" externalStation="70.000000"/>
                <CrossSectionSurfaces>
                    <CrossSectionSurface name="LIDAR existing conditions x-sections only" type="0">
                        <CrossSectionPoints>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735946.600165" easting="1692755.406158" offset="-12.000000" elevation="614.867040" flag="Begin"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="ExistingCenterline" northing="735937.599845" easting="1692763.343049" offset="0.000000" elevation="615.721052"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735928.599525" easting="1692771.279941" offset="12.000000" elevation="615.035679" flag="End"/>
                        </CrossSectionPoints>
                    </CrossSectionSurface>
                </CrossSectionSurfaces>
            </CrossSectionStation>
            <CrossSectionStation leftOffset="-15.000000" rightOffset="15.000000" tangentialDirection="0.848102" radialDirection="2.418899" northing="735944.213921" easting="1692770.843316" elevation="615.711238" longitudinalGrade="0.000373">
                <Station internalStation="80.000000" externalStationName="" externalStation="80.000000"/>
                <CrossSectionSurfaces>
                    <CrossSectionSurface name="LIDAR existing conditions x-sections only" type="0">
                        <CrossSectionPoints>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735953.214241" easting="1692762.906424" offset="-12.000000" elevation="614.853820" flag="Begin"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="ExistingCenterline" northing="735944.213921" easting="1692770.843316" offset="0.000000" elevation="615.711238"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735935.213602" easting="1692778.780207" offset="12.000000" elevation="615.116099" flag="End"/>
                        </CrossSectionPoints>
                    </CrossSectionSurface>
                </CrossSectionSurfaces>
            </CrossSectionStation>
            <CrossSectionStation leftOffset="-15.000000" rightOffset="15.000000" tangentialDirection="0.848102" radialDirection="2.418899" northing="735950.827997" easting="1692778.343582" elevation="615.684421" longitudinalGrade="-0.002888">
                <Station internalStation="90.000000" externalStationName="" externalStation="90.000000"/>
                <CrossSectionSurfaces>
                    <CrossSectionSurface name="LIDAR existing conditions x-sections only" type="0">
                        <CrossSectionPoints>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735959.828317" easting="1692770.406691" offset="-12.000000" elevation="614.915867" flag="Begin"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="ExistingCenterline" northing="735950.827997" easting="1692778.343582" offset="0.000000" elevation="615.684421"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735941.827678" easting="1692786.280473" offset="12.000000" elevation="615.071944" flag="End"/>
                        </CrossSectionPoints>
                    </CrossSectionSurface>
                </CrossSectionSurfaces>
            </CrossSectionStation>
            <CrossSectionStation leftOffset="-15.000000" rightOffset="15.000000" tangentialDirection="0.848102" radialDirection="2.418899" northing="735957.442041" easting="1692785.843811" elevation="615.632357" longitudinalGrade="-0.006180">
                <Station internalStation="99.999950" externalStationName="" externalStation="99.999950"/>
                <CrossSectionSurfaces>
                    <CrossSectionSurface name="LIDAR existing conditions x-sections only" type="0">
                        <CrossSectionPoints>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735966.442343" easting="1692777.906935" offset="-11.999977" elevation="614.938506" flag="Begin"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="ExistingCenterline" northing="735957.442024" easting="1692785.843826" offset="0.000023" elevation="615.632356"/>
                            <CrossSectionPoint type="CrossSectionPoint" northing="735948.441704" easting="1692793.780717" offset="12.000023" elevation="614.966179" flag="End"/>
                        </CrossSectionPoints>
                    </CrossSectionSurface>
                </CrossSectionSurfaces>
            </CrossSectionStation>
        </CrossSectionStations>
    </CrossSectionSet>
</InRoads>
```

Comment: How do you run the XSLT, which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: Not that this answers your question, but why do you even need to go into Javascript for such trivial task? https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ4M

Comment: If you run `cscript -?` from a command line prompt on the system where the JScript code used in your XSLT fails to give the wanted result, which version of "Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host" does it show? When JScript started to support `toFixed`, I think it was buggy for numerous editions. But that is rather long in the past, old archives of the comp.lang.javascript FAQ used to say "However, there are bugs in JScript 5.8 and below with certain values; for example, `0.007.toFixed(2)` incorrectly returns "0.00"".

Comment: Good Morning Martin, This is just one of many reports (XSL files) that can be run against a XML file that is derived from all the elements within a dgn CADD file (arcs, lines, etc.).  All of the creation of the CADD elements, the exporting of element information to XML and running the XSL (report) is done within the CADD program which uses MSXML 6SP 1 parser.  Sorry about the delay in my response but StackOverFlow is new to me.

Comment: Morning michael.hor257k, That's a good question.  The other reports (XSL files) always used JavaScript when running numerical operations so I just followed suit.  I don't claim to be a programmer so always think its best to try and follow rather than venture off the trail.  I'll look into adapting my Stylesheet to do everything within XSLT.

Comment: Unfortunately our CADD program dates back to 2006 and these Stylesheets use the defuncted version 1.1 but I have no idea how problematic of using this version is?

Comment: Guys, I ran with michael.hor257k suggestion and replaced my JavaScript function with ```<xsl:value-of select="format-number((($list[2]/@elevation - $list[1]/@elevation) div $list[1]/@offset), '0.00%')"/>``` and I still get the same results that I did with JavaScript.  Question, I don't have to declare the type of numbers I'm using do I?

Comment: And Thanks michael.hor257k for showing me "xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net", That's Pretty Handy!

Comment: It would be a good idea to try to reduce the samples, both the input and the XSLT, to be minimal but complete to just demonstrate the problem with the number computation. Then it will be easier to tell where things go wrong.

Comment: There should be no problem with using XSLT 1.1. The code I posted is pure XSLT 1.0 and should work with any conforming processor. If you're not getting the expected result, then most likely the input is not what you think it is. Unfortunately, you did not post a [mcve] so we cannot verify that.

Comment: P.S. The one to thank for https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net is Martin Honnen - it's his site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael.hor257k was right, my XML & XSLT are producing the correct result using the input values to the 6th place.  It was my checks done by hand that were using values to the 2nd place was where the whole source of my distress lay.